# Teradata14 reversing the words in string

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to reverse the words in the string in teradata 14.

Ex: 'jai Keith pavan ram' is input. Output should be 'ram pavan Keith jai'. I need dynamic logic for this. It should applicable to this I/p also.

'ram sita Laxmi' should give o/p as 'Laxmi sita ram'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE to split the string based on any delimiter. The split strings are called tokens and given a tokennum based on their order.
Then use XMLAGG to tie them together, this time ordering the tokens in descending order of token number.

```
select
     xmlagg(d.token order by tokennum desc) (varchar(100)) AS reversed_string
    from
     table (strtok_split_to_table(1, 'Teradata14 reversing the words in string', ' ')
     returns (outkey integer, tokennum integer, token varchar(20)character set unicode)) as d;

 *** Query completed. One row found. One column returned. 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

reversed_string
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string in words the reversing Teradata14
```

Comment: @Ear A Peach...excellent...never thought of it...but will it work in TD 14.00.00.01 version ?

Comment: Works on my TD version 14.10.06.04

Answer (score 0):

Adi, Since the contents in your columns is not fixed .For dynamic data you have two options ,
1.Write an SP
2.Handle it in unix script .Write a data to a file , modify it using AWK and then reload.

Written shell sample

```
###Script to export the results to the file###

rm -f Script.log
bteq << EOF >> Script.log 2>&1
.logon <ip or hostname>/<USR>,<PWD>
.OS rm -f Temp_export.out
.SET WIDTH 1000
.export REPORT FILE=Temp_export.out
Select
cast(cast(id as varchar(10))||','||cast(name as varchar(100)) as varchar(111))
 from DB_SOK.testTable;
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF
.export reset
.logoff
.quit
EOF
#####removed the top two files from the report generated from previous ######

 tail -n +3 Temp_export.out > temp_export_removed_header

rm -f temp_import

#######reverse the words using AWK in unxi ############################
while read LINE
do
x=`echo $LINE|cut -f1 -d','`
y=`echo $LINE|cut -f2 -d','|awk '{ for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf("%s ",$i); print $1; }';`

echo $x,$y >> temp_import

done < temp_export_removed_header

#####script to import results to the table ####

bteq << EOF
.logon <ip or hostname>/<USR>,<PWD>

.import vartext ',' file =temp_import
database <DB_NAME>;
.quiet on;
.repeat *;
using
id (varchar(10)),
name (varchar(100))
insert into testTable2 (id,name)
values
(
:id,
:name
);
 .logoff
.quit
EOF
```

Hope it will solve your temporarily ...:)
if i will get a time will try to write an SP.